# Application tried to push a nil view controller on target

Tags: ios, uitableview, push

I got the below error:

`Application tried to push a nil view controller on target UINavigationController: 0x7b98940.`

It is caused when I 'click' a cell of an `UITableViewController`.
Code:

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VerifyInfoViewController *verifyInfoVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"verifyInfoVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:verifyInfoVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: did you set your VerifyInfoViewController's Storyboard ID as verifyInfoVC in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes, but it still doesn't works...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This error means your `ViewController` has not been allocated properly, and i guess `self.storyboard` is nil, If yes this means you didn't initialise your master `viewController` and you can do the below trick:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

Comment: Fantastic! One more question... I should do this every time I use 'self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithName' ?

Thanks!

Comment: No it is not necessary, you can keep the object somewhere and keep using it (after initializing).