# Manually push a view to another view (ObjC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard, segue

I am stuck at this since 2 days now, searched almost 27 diff stackoverflow answers yet cannot do it
I want to manually push my view to a different view, I created a Segue with it with identifier gameView and tried using prepareForSegueWithIdentifier method but it doesnt works, always says my viewController cannot find a segue with identifier "gameView" even though it exists.

Here are some screenshots for better understanding:

[image: The Segue in my storyboard]

[image: The Code to push to gameViewController]

[image: The Error, btw it doesnt reach prepareForSegue part]

Earlier on I was using same code which is in prepareForSegue (wasnt using manual push so no prepareWithIdentifier) since earlier I was pushing view from cell selection and it was working, but now I need to push the view manually due to implementing async tasks etc.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: What controller is the segue connected to?

Comment: Where did you connect the segue from? Directly from the controller, GDmainTableViewController?

Comment: GDmainTableView (see image 2), its connected from GDmainTableView to GDgameView (image 1) @developerdoug

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by image 1 and 2, but if you're doing a manual segue, the connection has to be made from the controller itself, not the table view or cell -- you should control drag from the controller icon at the bottom of the scene.

Comment: @rdelmar yes see above comment, its directly from one VC to another VC (selected the yellow icon to drag)

Comment: If that's so, it should work. You might try cleaning the project, shutting down Xcode and restarting. It could be that something got messed up when you were making changes.

Comment: @rdelmar thats the first things I always do when something doesnt work as it was supposed to, but it didnt help, my hunch is its something to do with the segue itself or either the code to call it but not sure what exactly (am new)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42248/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-vongolashu)

Comment: After looking at you project, there are a bunch of problems with it that are too numerous for me to give you an easy fix. You have way too many class methods that should be instance methods. The method that's the problem here is a class method in GDaiViewController -- that's where you should call a delegate method on GCMainTableViewController, but you can't because you can't reference instance variables (_delegate) in a class method. You could post a notification from operationCompleted (the one in GDMainTableViewController) and that will fix this particular problem. Continued in next comment

Comment: If you add an observer for that notification in GDMainTableViewController, and make the selector be operationCompleted, then that method will be called on your correct instance. But then other errors crop up. I think you should delete this question, because the problem has nothing to do with the way you're doing the segue -- it's because the instance where you're trying to call performSegue is not the one in the storyboard, and so  it has no segue, as the error message states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your project I saw that u were using segue, and made a mess out of it which confused the program, I removed it and made the selecting system with the delegate method for UITableView

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And then process some data and when its done I present the right ViewController using the method

```
presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animate:(BOOL)animate completion:^{block}
```

Comment: what does ID refer to ? ID of storyboard or the VC I want to change to ? Where can I set this ID, identity inspector ?

Comment: Okay so I set the ID (img 1), used your code (img 2) and got the error (img 3)

1. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7thdxx7fh4ap7d4/Screenshot%202013-12-01%2000.11.14.png
2. https://www.dropbox.com/s/mkan88o0r282xt3/Screenshot%202013-12-01%2000.12.16.png
3. https://www.dropbox.com/s/gaydmtksjy3ze4i/Screenshot%202013-12-01%2000.12.57.png

Comment: Try to comment out the dismissViewController. As Im thinking that makes the current VC NULL and when you later try to call presentViewController: it doesnt work because self is NULL

Comment: btw should I use UIViewController or GDgameViewController while making vc object ?

Comment: make it UIViewController

Comment: didnt worked, tried the edit, commented what you said, same error

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the second line of my code and run it, when it breaks hover with the mouse over the first line of my code, after a little delay a window will pop up and then if it says nil I think I know what the problem is.

Comment: I have replied back in the chat discussion after trying to load data in gameView, will await your reply. Though I think the initial pushing of view is done with what you mentioned above, just pushing/showing data with it is left

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewControllerYouWantToChangeTo *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ID"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

ID refer to storyboard or the VC you want to change to

and instead of using

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];//<-- this could cause a warning
```

use :

```
[[[self parentViewController] parentViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I don't have the ability to comment so posted it as an answer

Comment: didnt worked, see the comment I made to @Arbitur's answer, same error as that

Comment: nope didnt worked after all edits, Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <GDmainTableViewController: 0x8d80df0>.

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819826/application-tried-to-push-a-nil-view-controller-on-target)